# Selecting data in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, if-statement, filter

I have a list of strings, and I would like to do a filter, using 2 words combined. As example:

```
list_words = ['test cat dog tree',
       'bird time headphone square',
        'cow light gate white', 
        'soccer baseball box volley',
        'clock universe god peace']

word1 = 'gate'
word2 = 'white'
```

In this example, I would like to return the list item on position [2]: 'cow light gate white', once the user has added two words that is combined with the entire phrase.
Seems easy, but I am really stuck on it.

Comment: `l = [i for i in list_words if str(word1 + ' ' +word2).lower() in i.lower()]`

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but if you define `words = ['gate', 'white']`, you can try `list(filter(lambda x:all(w in x for w in words), list_words)`

Answer (score 1):

One approach, that works for any number of words inputed by the user, is to use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
res = [sentence for sentence in list_words if all(w in sentence for w in [word1, word2])]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['cow light gate white']
```

The above [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is equivalent to the below *for*-loop:

```
test_words = [word1, word2]
res = []
for sentence in list_words:
    if all(w in sentence for w in test_words):
        res.append(sentence)
        
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) operations.

You want to check is the set of your words is a subset of the words of the strings, use [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
W = {word1, word2}

out = [s for s in list_words if W.issubset(s.split())]
```

Output:

```
['cow light gate white']
```